# How do I read / interpret this Kotlin code effectively?

Tags: kotlin

I know how to read/interpret Java code and I can write it. However being new to kotlin I find code like below hard to read. Perhaps I am missing key concepts in the language.

But, how would you go about interpreting this code? Where do you propose one to start reading it in order to understand this piece of code quickly and efficiently? Left to right? Right to left? Break down parameters first? Look at return values?

```
inline fun <T : Any, R> ifNotNull(input: T?, callback: (T) -> R): R? {
    return input?.let(callback)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt's answer explains everything well in one go; I'll try to look at *how* you might go about reading such code.

Skipping over the first word for now, the most important thing is the second word: `fun`.  So *the whole thing is defining a function*.  That tells you what to expect from the rest.

The braces tell you that it's a block function, not a one-liner, so the basic structure you're expecting is: `fun name(params): returnType { code }`.  The rest is filling in the blanks!  (This fits the general pattern of Kotlin declarations, where the type comes second, after a colon.  The Java equivalent would of course be more like `returnType name(params) { code }`.)

As with Java, the stuff in angle brackets is giving generic parameters, so we can skip that for now and go straight to the next most important bit, which is *the name of the function being defined*: `ifNotNull`.

Armed with those, we can read the rest.  `inline` is a simple *modifier*, telling you that the function will be inlined by the compiler.  (That enables a few things and restricts a few others, but I wouldn't worry about that now.)

The `<T : Any, R>` gives the *generic parameter types* that the function uses.  The first is `T`, which must be `Any` or a subtype; the second is `R`, which is unrestricted.

(`Any` is like Java's `Object`, but can't be `null`; the topmost type is the related `Any?`, which also allows `null`.  So except for the nullability, that's equivalent to the Java `<T extends Object, R>`.)

Going on, we have the *function parameters* in parentheses.  Again, there are two: the first is called `input`, and it's of type `T?`, which means it accepts any value of type `T`, and also accepts `null`.  The second parameter is called `callback`, and has a more complicated type, `(T) -> R`: it's a function which takes a `T` as its parameter, and returns an `R`.  (Java doesn't have function types as such, so that probably looks strangest.  Java's nearest equivalent is `Function<R, T>`.)

After the parentheses comes the *return type* of this function itself, `R?`, which means it can return either an `R` or `null`.

Finally, in braces is the actual *code* of the function.  That has one line, which returns the value of an expression.  (Its effect is to check whether the value of `input` is `null`: if so, it returns the `null` directly.  Otherwise, it calls the `callback` function given in the parameter, passing `input` as its parameter, and returns its result.)

Although that's a short declaration, it's quite abstract and packs a lot in, so it's no wonder you're finding it hard going!  (The format is similar to a Java method declaration — but Kotlin's quite expressive, so equivalent code tends to be quite a bit shorter than Java.  And the generics make it more complex.)  If you're just starting to learn Kotlin, I'd suggest something a bit easier :-)

(The good news is that, as in Java, you don't often need to read the stdlib code.  Although Kotlin's doc comments are rarely up to the exemplary level of Java's, they're still usually enough.)

Comment: This is what is was looking for. Judging from the answers my question seemed clear, so I would really appreciate a upvote!

Answer (score 4):

So, like Java this is a generic function. It has two type parameters T which is of type 'Any' ('Any' is like 'Object' in Java) and R. The input parameter is a nullable T, as denoted by the question mark. Nullable types mean that the value can be null. The other function parameter is a function that takes in a T (non nullable type) and returns R. The return type of the function is a nullable R. The body of the function says that if input is not null, call and pass that to the callback and return that value. If input is null, then null is what gets returned.

Comment: `T` is not "of type `Any`", it's any type which is a subtype of `Any`.

Comment: This adds value but I needed a more comprehensive answer. But judging from your answer my Q seemed clear, so I would really appreciate a upvote!

Answer (score 4):

Let's dissect the function definition piece by piece:

`inline`: Indicates that the code of the function will be copied directly to the call site, rather than being called like a normal function.

`fun`: We're defining a function.

`<T : Any, R>`: The function takes two generic type parameters, `T` and `R`. The `T` type is restricted to the `Any` type (which is Kotlin's `Object`-type). That might seem redundant, but what it actually says is that `T` cannot be a nullable type (`Any?`).

`ifNotNull`: The name of the function.

`input: T?`: The first parameter of type `T?`. We can put the `?` on the `T` type here because we restricted it to non-nullable types in the type declaration.

`callback: (T) -> R`: The second parameter is of type `(T) -> R`, which is a function type. It's the type of a function that takes a `T` as input and returns an `R`.

`: R?`: The function returns a value of type `R` or null.

`return input?.let(callback)`: The function body. The `let` function takes a function parameter, calls it with its receiver (`input`), and then returns the result of the function. The `?` after `input` says that `let` will be called only if `input` is not null. If `input` is null, then the expression will return null.

The function is equivalent to this Java method (except for the inlining and nullable types):

```
public <T, R> R ifNotNull(final T input, final Function<T, R> callback) {
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return callback.apply(input);
}
```

Comment: This also adds value but I needed the more wrapping text like gidds A. If you found my Q clear I would really appreciate a upvote.